# R ggplot + ggplotly: color scale doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Beginning with ggplotly, and I can't seem to figure out how to use the colour scale. Here's what I've got:

```
> dput(set.df)
structure(list(Set.name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("set_3_1", 
"set_3_2", "set_3_3", "set_3_4", "set_3_5", "set_3_6"), class = "factor"), 
    Set.size = c(36202L, 31389L, 74322L, 181981L, 204571L, 347844L
    ), TF.number = c(91, 16, 38, 91, 91, 91), Ref.set.size = c(3830L, 
    155L, 725L, 3830L, 3830L, 3830L), False.negatives = c(107L, 
    7L, 100L, 1159L, 1744L, 2310L), Sensitivity = c(0.972062663185379, 
    0.954838709677419, 0.862068965517241, 0.697389033942559, 
    0.544647519582245, 0.39686684073107), Specificity = c(0.0790835553530113, 
    0.296607846658412, 0.296159447758514, 0.300796981749767, 
    0.325487685108514, 0.451174177879625), Precision = c(0.00959662223642798, 
    0.00342695718619029, 0.00608000311296159, 0.0110294421274311, 
    0.0094999544585117, 0.0199195355603025)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
plot <- ggplot(set.df, aes(key=Set.name, size = Set.size, fill = TF.number, x = Specificity, y = Sensitivity)) + 
  geom_point(colour="#ffffff00") +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, linetype = "dotted", colour= 'blue') +
  scale_fill_continuous(low='skyblue', high='midnightblue')

ggplotly(plot, tooltip =  c("Set.name", "Set.size", "TF.number", "Ref.set.size", "False.negatives", "Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Precision"))
```

and the output is:

[image: output]

The points don't show up in the expected nuance of blue, and I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In L$marker$color[idx] <- aes2plotly(data, params, "fill")[idx] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Also, somehow the point size legend doesn't show up.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that the `fill` aesthetic for `geom_point()` is only applicable to certain shapes (ones that have a border).  This doesn't include the default shape so you need to use the `color` aesthetic instead.  As for why the size legend doesn't show, `ggplotly` doesn't yet natively support multiple legends.  See [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668).

```
myplot <- ggplot(set.df, aes(key = Set.name, size = Set.size, color = TF.number, x = Specificity, y = Sensitivity)) + 
  geom_point() +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, linetype = "dotted", colour= 'blue') +
  scale_color_continuous(low='skyblue', high='midnightblue')

ggplotly(myplot, tooltip =  c("Set.name", "Set.size", "TF.number", "Ref.set.size", "False.negatives", "Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Precision"))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, very subtle, thanks a lot! Any ides about why the color scale shows up in the legend part, and no the size scale?

Comment: @rioualen - yes, I edited in an explanation a few minutes ago.